# How can I show Git commit hashes in VS Code's Timeline view?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code to edit files that are part of a Git project. In VS Code's Timeline view, I can see one line for each previous commit of the selected file. For example:

[image: screenshot of Timeline view]

Each line includes the commit message of the corresponding commit, and that's helpful. But I want more: I want each line to start with the first characters of the Git hash (AKA "commit ID"). For example, I want each line to start with 661259, 76fb07, and so on, if those are the first characters of the relevant hashes. Is there a way to add this info to Timeline view?

I've Googled and looked through Stack Overflow, but I haven't found any clear answers to this question.

*Edit 2023-09-13:* I've opened a feature request to add this capability to Timeline view. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/192959. Please upvote the request if you would like to see the feature added to VS Code; if it isn't upvoted, the request will soon be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of there being a feature to enable display of commit hashes with git-related timeline entries. You can right click such entries, and you'll get a menu with an option to "Copy Commit ID". You can also use the filter to filter for only "Git History" entries.

I'd expect that if it were togglable, there'd be a setting with the prefix `git.timeline.`, but under settings with that prefix or just the prefix `timeline.`, there are no such settings.

I'm also not aware of how an extension could do this. Extension can contribute menu items to the context menu for timeline entries (see [`timeline/item/context`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.menus)), but I don't think they can add action buttons / decorations to the timeline entries themselves.

A feature request has been raised: [Show commit hashes in Timeline view #192959](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/192959).

Comment: @user697473 now that you've raised the feature-request, you need to get enough community support. I suggest you share the link on reddit (r/vscode) and to your dev friends/colleagues.

Comment: Thank you, @starball. That's a good idea. I [posted to r/vscode](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/16ic1p8/feature_request_display_commit_hashes_in_timeline/) and I'll reach out to others, too.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend a extention on VS Code for you. That's all you need. **GitLens**

Example:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Manh. I've been using GitLens and it does seem good. That said, I still want hashes to appear in Timeline view—it's a much lighter-weight change that could be quite helpful.